# How to add export button to html/jquery datatable code?

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, datatables, frontend

I have a code of html/jquery/bootstrap. I'm unable to add export button which will download the data which is in table format. How to add export button which will download the data in csv and excel format?

Below is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <!--link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='images/favicon.ico')}}"-->

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datatable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post">
<!--          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="user_csv"></textarea>-->
          <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Show output data</button>
        </form>
        <div class="mt-4">
          {% if request.method == 'POST'%}
            <table id="proxies" class="display table nowrap responsive" style="width: 100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {% for header in results[0].keys() %}
                    <th>{{header}}</th>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for row in results %}
                  <tr>
                    {% for index in range(0, len(fieldnames)) %}
                      <td>{{row[fieldnames[index]]}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#proxies').DataTable();
  </script>

</html>
```

**How to add export button which will download the data in csv and excel format?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding following code in your script.
Working example can be found [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)!

```js
$('#proxies').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
} );
```